# $Assumptions causing problems in Mathematica 12.3 vs. 10.4

Tags: assumptions, version-12.3, version-10.4

I would like to use `$Assumptions` to add global restrictions to the parameters in my notebook (Mathematica 12.3). I tried exactly this in Mathematica 10.4 and it works just fine.

In Mathematica 12.3, as long as the `$Assumptions` are not in place, the evaluation of the notebook also runs without a problem and gives straightforward results for commands such as `Solve` (`Solve[-G - \[Tau]H + \[Tau]L == 0, G]`), looking this way:

```
{{G -> -\[Tau]H + \[Tau]L}}
```

As soon as i add the `$Assumptions = {1 > \[Tau]H > 0, 1 > \[Tau]L > 0, \[Tau]H > \[Tau]L,  1 >= \[Gamma]s >= 0, 1 >= \[Gamma]c >= 0, 1 > r > 0, p > 0, y >= 0 , d > 0, q >= 0, FR > 0, FP > 0}`, Mathematica's output is conditional on some values, although to my understanding, `Solve` should not even use `$Assumptions`.
[image]
Also, Mathematica 12.3 is not able to calculate a simple derivation, set it equal to zero and solve for one parameter at a later point, `Solve[D[-(G^2/2) + (-FR + G + q) (1 - (1 + r)^-t \[Tau]H) + (-FP - G - q + d Sqrt[y]) (1 - \[Tau]L), G] == 0, G]`.

None of the `$Assumptions` is made up in a way that it would explain these problems. It also confuses me that these calculations run without a problem in Mathematica 10.4, with or without the global assumptions.

Please excuse the formulation of the question. I am an absolute beginner in Mathematica and haven't found any similar problem here. I am thankful for any help and happy to provide more info if necessary.

Comment: show your code please clearly, copy and paste !

Comment: I'm feeling this one too. Not a step in the right direction IMHO.